# Get all the possible combination which sum equal 20 in an array [1, 2 , 5, 9]?

Tags: algorithm

Get all the possible combination which sum equal 20 in an array [1, 2 , 5, 9] ,allowing repeat.
just like:

```
5+5+5+5=20;
1+9+5+5=20;
9+9+2=20;
9+5+1+1+1+1+1+1=20
etc.
```

please give me some hints, or something i can search in google.

Comment: Please have a look at [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) or consider recursion...

Comment: Exploration of a tree in which each node can have your numbers as children; cut the exploration when you get over 20 on your way down. Take the descending paths, sort them and store them in a set if you want unique combinations.

Answer (score 3):

### There are many possible approaches to this, here is one

1. Take the largest first (9)
2. Keep adding it to itself until you reach or exceed the target (20)
3. Either add the combination to your accepted list or don't, depending on whether it matches your target or not
4. If the last number in the combination is not the smallest in your array, replace the last iteration with the next largest and go back to step 2
5. Go back to the end of the chain of the first number and replace it with the next largest number

### For example:

9+9+9 = 27
Discard this answer
Replace the last iteration with the next largest, and repeat
9+9+5 = 23
Discard this answer
Replace the last iteration with the next largest, and repeat
9+9+2 = 20
Add this to your list of accepted combinations
Replace the last iteration with the next largest, and repeat
9+9+1+1 = 20
Add this to your list of accepted combinations
We are now at the end of the array (no more smaller numbers) so we must go back to the end of the chain of 9's and replace the last one with the next smallest and repeat

9+5+5+5 = 24
Discard this answer
Replace the last iteration with the next largest, and repeat
9+5+5+2 = 21
Discard this answer
Replace the last iteration with the next largest, and repeat
9+5+5+1 = 20
And so on...

Comment: @shapiroyaacov yes, absolutely. The OP appears to not know where to start though so telling him to "use recursion" is not as helpful as giving him an explanation of the logic as a solid starting point

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified/generalized example of the "knapsack problem" [(wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

The analogy is that you are presented with a fixed-size knapsack that you must fill with the most valuable combination of a particular set of items. In your case, the value of each item is ignored and you are just looking for all of the combinations of items that will fit in the knapsack of size 20.

Comment: I'm afraid that's more than the knapsack problem: he's asking to "get *all combinations*" (as in "list them all") not "the most valuable combination". I don't see how this can be solved without a full exploration of the tree.

Comment: @Adrian It seems to me that they're very closely related. Although it's probably more clear to consider the "subset sum problem" [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), a special case of the knapsack problem. There are lots of algorithms out there that seek to optimize efficiency in these particular problems including ones that "get all combinations" e.g. "Computing Partitions with Applications to the Knapsack Problem".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ([linky here](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/computingPartitions.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

While it can be applicable, there is no need for a recursive approach.

By dynamical programming you might come up with a solution as follows. I first establish a hash for all numbers from the minimum number in the given array to the target value. So in this case 1 -> 20. The dynamical part is all about making use of the previously constructed part of the hash table. Once we reach `hash[target]` we have the result.

I don't think this job can be done any faster than this. The given example resolves in less than 1ms resulting 42 combinations; while if the target is set as 100 it should solve in less than 300 msecs with 2360 different combinations of the given set of numbers array.

So for instance once we have finished the 6th iteration the hash table looks like;

```
{ '1': [ [ 1 ] ],
  '2': [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2 ] ],
  '3': [ [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ] ],
  '4': [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 2 ] ],
  '5': [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 2 ], [ 5 ] ],
  '6': [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 1, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ], [ 1, 5 ] ],
  '7': ...
```

The code in JS is as follows;

```js
function getCombos(a,t){
  var hash = {};
  
  for (var i = Math.min(...a); i <= t; i++)
    a.forEach(e => e <= i && (hash[i] ? hash[i-e] ? hash[i] = hash[i].concat(hash[i-e].reduce((p,f) => f.some(n => n > e) ? p : (p.push(f.concat(e)),p),[]))
                                                  : hash[i].push([e])
                                      : hash[i-e] ? hash[i] = hash[i-e].reduce((p,f) => f.some(n => n > e) ? p : (p.push(f.concat(e)),p),[])
                                                  : hash[i] = [[e]]));
  return hash[t];
}


var arr = [1, 2, 5, 9],
 target = 20;
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(getCombos(arr,target)));
```

I had to re invent this algo for better performance. Here it is;

```js
function getCombos(a,t){
  var h = {},
    len = a.length,
      n = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    n = a[i];
    h[n] ? h[n].push([n]) : h[n] = [[n]];
    for(var j = a[0]; j <= t; j++){
      h[j] && (h[j+n] = h[j+n] ? h[j+n].concat(h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)))
                               : h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)));
    }
  }
  return h[t] || [];
}

var arr = [1,2,5,9],
 target = 20,
 result = [];
console.time("combos");
result = getCombos(arr,target);
console.timeEnd("combos");
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thanks firstly, what does 'h[j+n] = h[j+n]'  mean?

Comment: @DavidJ We are to assign a value to `h[j+n]` so for that reason `h[j+n] =` on the left. However on the right side we have a ternary conditional `h[j+n] ? h[j+n].concat(h[j].map(s => s.concat(n))) : h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)));` which means if `h[j+n]` is truthy (or if it exists) then do `h[j+n].concat(h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)))` else do `h[j].map(s => s.concat(n)));`